# ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm new to webpack / reactjs, just follow the tutorial here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_environment_setup.htm

Then after I 'npm start', I got error:

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel' in '/var/www/jay/reactjs/react-app'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'babel-loader' instead of 'babel'.
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./main.js
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

The tutorial you are following uses Webpack 1, but you are now using Webpack 2 which has some breaking changes. The error tells you that you can no longer omit `-loader` when specifying your loaders. All you need to do is replace

```
loader: 'babel'
```

with

```
loader: 'babel-loader'
```

To see what else you might need to change, you can have a look at the migration guide from the official docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

Comment: its interesting OP has not marked this as correct answer. Works just fine. In fact I had to do 1 another change from the tutorial example

Answer (score 1):

Error in angular dependencies. It may be with renaming files or folders in angular.json

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add babel-loader as part of your dev dependencies by runnning `npm install --save-dev babel-loader`.
This adds `babel-loader` to your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

For vue cli 3 projects with vue-cli-plugin-vuetify, try removing vue-cli-plugin-vuetify vuetify-loader from devDependencies and then removing vuetify itself.

Credits:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/bp3kcu/uninstalling_vuetify_from_project/